# Goodness of fit ranking for several models

Tags: model-selection, goodness-of-fit

I have some data that I am trying to fit with different models: exponential, sum of two exponentials, hyperbolic secant, etc.
I would like to have a criteria to be able to rank the different models and decide which one is the best fit.
I know the Kolmogorov-Smirnov or Anderson-Darling criteria, and how to use them to decide whether it is possible that some data come from a certain distribution or not, but don't know whether their statistic parameters can also be used to compare between different models and rank them. I have also read that the AIC or the BIC could be good options for my purposes, but I have also read that they are bad options exactly for this task...
Any thoughts, ideas or resources would be helpful